# Android avd manager not working at all

Tags: android

I have recently thought I would try to create a android app I downloaded the Android sdk pack and extracted it to my c: drive (but I did not get an install screen to install it) i then opened eclipse and clicked on the sdk manager for the Android packages this all worked fine downloaded all the packages as far back as the 2.2 gingerbread as recommended but this is where my problems began I tried to open emulator manager to create the emulator but nothing happened it did not say a error or any thing it just did nothing so I can not even try to create the emulator any advice would be much appreciated as i said the sdk manager works fine but the avd manager will not do any thing at all

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (restart eclipse)

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply yes I have turned it off and on I have restarted my computer and I have also deleted it off my computer and re downloaded it but it just won't do any thing when I click on the avd manager

Comment: you first need to create a new AVD in the AVD manager. Then click Start

Comment: also, the emulator takes a few seconds to start, and quite a long time to get fully started

Comment: I know I need to create a avd but I can not it will not let me start the avd manager to be able to create the emulator its starting the manager that will not work when I click on the manager nothing at all happens