# android virtual device manager(avd) not working in latest adt v21

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

Well, I was using Indigo with `ADT v20` and everything was just fine, but I suddenly received an annoying update message to update the `sdk`.

When I updated the `sdk`, I got another issue that I need to update the `adt` due to the current version of the `sdk` not supporting the old `adt`. So I did and now clicking on `AVD Manager` shortcut or going  through `Windows->AVD Manager` is not working. Nothing happens when I click there. Some of my friends are also facing the same problem with Win7 and Ubuntu.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381177/android-avd-manager-not-working-at-all). But I don't know why that question is closed.

Comment: Hi there, Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13761137/1105291

Answer (score 1):

If you open eclipse's log file, called .log in the .metadata directory (which is in your workspace) you likely have the following exception:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-12-06 14:17:03.497
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getDeviceName(AvdInfo.java:158)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.fillDevices(DeviceManagerPage.java:497)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.fillTable(DeviceManagerPage.java:357)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.createContents(DeviceManagerPage.java:259)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.(DeviceManagerPage.java:130)

See this link for the fix:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40400

I will warn you that they will tell you to install "Tools 21.0.1 preview 1".  They seemed to have changed the name to "Android Development Tools".

I installed it and it works for me now.

Comment: Well i uninstall "SDk". and made fresh install of all "Eclipse, ADT, SDK" now thing are working correctly. from having many try on different machines i come to conclusion that we should update "ADT" before "SDK". I know it sound weird but things are working this way.

Comment: but any ways Thanks Cris for your help.

if anybody found Cris's solution working perfectly then please inform me i will mark it as "Correct Answer" to help others

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the AVD Manager with admin rights.
Or, the easy way: start it outside from eclipse and create your virtual devices there.